# Remove object from array with a 0 value

Tags: javascript

I am generating an array with objects from some outside data. Here is my code to do so:

```
  modifyFatalitiesByCause(data) {
    let array = [];
    for (let x in data) {
      array.push({
        "name": data[x]['HarmfulEvent'],
        "value": parseInt(data[x]['Deaths']),
      })
    }
    return array;
  }
```

This works fine and will output this data (here's just a small chunk of a big array):

```
[
    {name: "Injured in Vehicle (Non-Collision)", value: 1},
    {name: "Fire Hydrant", value: 1},
    {name: "Snow Bank", value: 0},
    {name: "Cargo/Equipment", value: 0}
]
```

I would like to not have the objects with a value of `0` appear in my array. Will I need to remove these at the end or can I modify my `for x in data` loop to only push the objects that don't have a value of `0`?

Which is the easier solution?

Comment: `array.filter(x => x.value)` ? or simply add an `if` condition before you `push` to check that `data[x]['Deaths'] !== 0`

Comment: So add an if check before you add it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove them all at the end but it would be more efficient to just not push them to your array while you're building it. 
Something like this:

```
if (parseInt(data[x]['Deaths']) { // 0 is falsey
  array.push({
    "name": data[x]['HarmfulEvent'],
    "value": parseInt(data[x]['Deaths']),
  });
}
```

Comment: @cup_of you should accept this answer or the [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52119901/5909281) by amrender_singh

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do a check before pushing element on array like this `if(parseInt(data[x]['Deaths']) > 0` and then push **non-zero** values but [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) seems cool to me :)

```js
let array = [{
    name: "Injured in Vehicle (Non-Collision)",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Fire Hydrant",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Snow Bank",
    value: 0
  },
  {
    name: "Cargo/Equipment",
    value: 0
  }
];
result = array.filter(elm => elm.value > 0);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I went with M. Wyatt's solution. gave you an upvote

Comment: @cup_of awesome. It's OK you can go with `if(parseInt(data[x]['Deaths'])> 0`  way no prob. Best of luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a check in your  `for` loop, Add objects in your array, whose `data[x]['Deaths'])` are non-zero. Try the following:

```
for (let x in data) {
     if(parseInt(data[x]['Deaths']) != 0){
       array.push({
         "name": data[x]['HarmfulEvent'],
         "value": parseInt(data[x]['Deaths']),
       })
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is always best to create a predicated if statement to check the validation before the business logic execute. Here is my solution to solve this problem.

```
  modifyFatalitiesByCause(data) {
    let array = [];
    for (let record in data) {
     if(isDeathCountZero(record, data)){
       array.push({
         "name": data[record]['HarmfulEvent'],
         "value": parseInt(data[record]['Deaths']),
       });
     } 
   }
    return array;
  }

 isDeathCountZero(record, data){
    return (parseInt(data[record]['Deaths']) != 0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use array filter to filter the results.
refrence:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter